# NodeJS db-migrate TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: node.js, npm, dbmigrate

I've just installed the nodejs package db-migrate into an existing nodejs project. Everything seems to be configured correctly in regards to the connection to the DB.

Database.json:

```
{
    "development": "postgres://blabla",
    "production": "postgres://blabla"
}
```

Migration:

```
var dbm = global.dbm || require('db-migrate');
var type = dbm.dataType;

exports.up = function(db, callback) {
    db.createTable('users', {
        id: { type: 'int', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        username: { type: 'string', unique: true }
        }, callback);
};

exports.down = function(db, callback) {
    db.dropTable('users', callback);
};
```

Whenever I try to run `db-migrate up` (with any variation of parameters like specifying the database file, the migration, the number of migrations, etc), the command raises an error every time:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
   at Class.extend.parseName (C:\Users\test\Projects\nodejs\cirio-crm\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\skeleton.js:162:17)
   at Class.Skeleton.extend.init (C:\Users\test\Projects\nodejs\cirio-crm\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\migration.js:35:24)
   at Class.prototype.(anonymous function) [as init] (C:\Users\test\Projects\nodejs\cirio-crm\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\class.js:36:24)
   at new Class (C:\Users\test\Projects\nodejs\cirio-crm\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\class.js:49:17)
   at C:\Users\test\Projects\nodejs\cirio-crm\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\migration.js:312:14
   at Array.map (native)
   at C:\Users\test\Projects\nodejs\cirio-crm\node_modules\db-migrate\lib\migration.js:311:35
   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

I've tried renaming the table, changing the fields, messing with the CRLF line endings, installing different versions of nodejs and db-migrate, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After about an hour of running in circles I realized the migration was named incorrectly. Its first part only specified the date and not the time. The correct file name format to be used would be `yyyyMMddhhmmss-<some text>`.

Before (Bad): `20160101-testmigration`

After (Good): `20160101000000-testmigration`

The error could have been more explicit though...

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @2Toad, one has to be careful about what is stored on the folder where migrations are supposed to be found. If you have any `*.js` file that doesn't follow the naming format, like a helper JS file, the same error will occur.

Comment: Can you please clarify what did you changed exactly. I did run into same issue. But I don't have any migration named that way

Comment: @UmakantPatil All I did was naming the migration with the following format: `yyyyMMddhhmmss-<some text>`

Comment: Might want to check for temp/backup/system files created by IDE/OS in the migrations folder. In my case, I had added a helper lib to the migrations folder, thinking db-migrate would only pull in files that matched the db-migrate naming convention: `YYYYMMDDHHmmss-{NAME}.js`. Apparently, that's not the case. db-migrate will attempt to parse all *.js files in the migrations folder